# Scope resolution operator on object

Tags: c++, operators, c++03, type-resolution

In C++ we have an `operator::`, which allows us to do things like that:

```
typedef std::pair<A, B> pairAB;
pairAB p;

pairAB::first_type a(42);
pairAB::second_type b("hello world");

p.first = a;
p.second = b;
```

I tried to use this operator on the object of this type:

```
pairAB p2;

p2::first_type a2(42);
p2::second_type b2("hello again");

p2.first = a2;
p2.second = b2;
```

And the compiler showed me `error: C2510: 'p2' : left of '::' must be a class/struct/union`, and I want to know is there any trick which allows me to do that?

Comment: Did you *try* it ?

Comment: @WhozCraig I've edited my question to explain what you're asking about

Comment: You mean something like `decltype(p2.first) a2(42);` ?

Comment: `decltype` is intresting, but I can't currently use c++11 or above

Comment: bummer, than I think you're SoL. Let it breathe awhile and see if someone can think of something crafty.

Comment: `SoL`? What does that means?

Comment: Do you have access to [typeof](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) ?

Comment: @steiner no, I'm using MSVC 9.0 furthermore I shouldn't write any platform- or compiler-dependent things

Comment: Any reason why you can't just write `pairAB::first_type` ?

Comment: Missing code which declares the types A and B.

Comment: @user31264 Does it matter?

Comment: @Sean In my opinion it's more convenient to work with a variable rather than with huge template-type, furthermore if you change the type of the variable all types we get from it will change too

Comment: If you know the type is a `pair` and it's called, say, T (in a template) you can just `typename T::first_type ...`. `pair` provides its type information (in C++03 and 11/onward).

Comment: There's no reason to avoid writing `pairAB::first_type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the type of a variable is exactly what `decltype` keyword is for in c++11.

```
decltype(p2.first) a2 = 42;
```

Prior to c++11 there was no standard way to do that. There are compiler specific features such as gcc's `typeof` and library based implementations such as Boost.Typeof that have existed prior to c++11 and do a similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GCC, there is a pre-C++11 equivalent called `__typeof__` that behaves similarly. Try:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
  typedef std::pair<int, std::string> pairAB;
  pairAB p2;

  __typeof__(p2.first) a2 = 42;
  __typeof__(p2.second) b2 = "hello again";

  p2.first = a2;
  p2.second = b2;
}
```

[Example here.](http://ideone.com/CCV34d)

Alternatively, if you can use [boost](http://www.boost.org/), it provides [Boost.typeof](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/typeof/refe.html#typeof.typo) which should work in older Visual C++ compilers as well.

Comment: It's a good idea, but it's actually more verbose then just typing `pairAB::first_type`

Comment: @Sean yes, it is more verbose; but I assume the poster had a reason why he wanted to avoid writing that.

Answer (score -1):

There's no need for C++11 features nor compiler extensions like `typeof` in C++03, which are not portable. If the variable is being used, its type is available somewhere -let's say it is T in a template or a function signature.

Then you can simply `typename T::first_type` since `pair` carries with itself member type information for its member types (as do many other STL classes such as containers, `string`, ...).

Comment: TY, I know about advantages of typedefs. As you can see I've used them in example. My question is not about "How should I do this?"  but about "How can I use a variable as typename (or namespace resolver)?"